# uploading large file to AWS aurora postgres serverless

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pgadmin-4, aws-aurora-serverless

I have been trying for days to copy a large CSV file to a table in PostgreSQL I am using PGadmin4 to access the database. I have a file on my system the file is 10 GB so I am getting starting error when trying to upload it via UI or \copy command.

Comment: Please show the actual error message, not your paraphrasing of it.

Comment: hey sorry, It was a database issue able to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When talking about 10 GB CSV file, then you may use as well different options

- I believe `\copy` should work, you did not provide any more information about the issue
- I'd personally use the AWS Glue - an ETL service which could read from an S3 file